# karma-webpack sourcemaps not working (Type script files not load to web browser for debug)

Tags: webpack, karma-runner, karma-webpack

I'm using Karma-Webpack. Karma Webpack sourcemaps not working

When I execute tests using karma in Chrome, the source files for my specs appear unreadable in the debugger. However, the system under test files (my application source) is unreadable

java script load to browser so, very difficult to debug. anyone can help me to load type script to

Spec file in debugger

[image]

webpack.test.config.js

```js
var path = require('path'),
    webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    output: {},
    cache: {},
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        alias: {
            "cldr": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/cldrjs/dist/cldr")
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
            filename: null,
            test: /\.(ts|js)($|\?)/i
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            },
            { test: /\.html$/i, use: 'html-loader' },
            {
                test: /\.(js|ts)$/,
                enforce: 'post',
                loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
                query: {
                    esModules: true
                },
                exclude: [
                    /index\.ts/,
                    /\.spec\.js$/,
                    /\.t\.ts$/,
                    /node_modules/,
                    /.bin/,
                    /decompressionworker\.ts/,
                    /\.(glsl|vs|fs)$/
                ]
            }]
    },
    watch: false
};
```

karma.config

```js
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Wed Oct 18 2017 11:50:04 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)
var webpackConfig = require('../webpack.test.config');

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    files: [
       { pattern: "../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js", include: true },
      './karma-bundle.js'
    ],

    webpack: webpackConfig,

    preprocessors: {
      './karma-bundle.js': ['webpack']
    },

    webpackMiddleware: {
      stats: 'normal'
    },

    plugins: [
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-mocha-reporter'),
      require('karma-webpack'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter')
    ],

    client: {
      clearContext: false,
    },

    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'coverage-istanbul'],

    port: 9876,

    colors: true,

    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    autoWatch: true,

    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    singleRun: false,

    concurrency: Infinity,

    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
           reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
           dir: 'coverage',
           fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
           skipFilesWithNoCoverage: true,
           'report-config': {
             html: {
               subdir: 'html'
             }
           },

           thresholds: {
             emitWarning: true, // set to `true` to not fail the test command when thresholds are not met
             global: { // thresholds for all files
               statements: 100,
               lines: 100,
               branches: 100,
               functions: 100
             }
           }

         }
  })
}
```

karma-bundle.js

```js
const tests = require.context('./ClientApp/views', true, /\.spec.ts$/);
tests.keys().forEach(tests);
```